# Fail to import images due to unicode decode error

Tags: python

I have added the add-ons, Import Images as Planes, and followed the same steps to import a PNG imagine as background or a plane. However, both of these steps failed with this unicode decode error.
The version of my Blender is 2.90.
Any help would be much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Using a proper file name and path? eg. `'C://foo/bar.png'` but not `C://foo/照片.png`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This problem has been solved after changing the file path. It seems like my Onedrive path is improper.